# Building our own cellRenderer with grouping functionality in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

Previously I had `columnDefs` for rendering ag-grid cells without Angular Components with the built-in **grouping** functionality.

```
colDef = [
            {
                headerName: 'HeaderName',
                field: 'a',
                editable: false,
                cellRenderer: 'group',
                ...
            },
```

Now I tried to use Angular components to render ag-grid cells with `cellRendererFramework` but it made me lose my grouping functionality. **The tree group values with expand / collapse functionality do not work anymore.**

```
colDef = [
            {
                headerName: 'HeaderName',
                field: 'a',
                editable: false,
                cellRendererFramework: MyCustomCellRendererComponent,
                ...
            },
```

Do I need to set grouping manually?

I have also tried using `groupRowInnerRenderer`, `innerRendererFramework`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I imagine you want to do something like the example at the bottom of [this page](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#gsc.tab=0). Basically all you need to change is this:

```
{
    headerName: 'HeaderName',
    field: 'a',
    editable: false,
    cellRenderer: 'group',
    cellRendererParams: {
        innerRendererFramework: MyCustomCellRendererComponent
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but there are errors using. Answer solved with cellRenderer: 'group', and innerRendererFramework

Comment: Thanks @Danaley I have updated the answer to reflect your experience

Comment: Can you please guide me in MyCustomCellRendererComponent how can we integrate a custom react component like link or label something. Thanks