# Is it possible to provide Component as Cell Renderer for tree data group in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Documentation gives only example with Simple Cell Renderer. (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/)
But what if I need more complex cell rendering for tree data group, can I use an angular component then, instead of a simple function?

Answer (score 1):

I Already have same problem with Custom Group Component Render.

When use `cellRendererFramework` property like any Column definition will not works, In Case Group Column you need use `innerRendererFramework` property into `cellRendererParams` Object property.

**Example** from [answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48390888/1908296):

```
{
    headerName: 'Group',
    cellRenderer: 'group',
    cellRendererParams: {
        innerRendererFramework: MyCustomCellRendererComponent
    }
}
```

**Notice:** this works into Columns definitions under both Ag-grid `columnDefs` Or `defaultColGroupDef` Or `autoGroupColumnDef` Inputs **(works for me using `autoGroupColumnDef`)**

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48390888/1908296
- https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/group-cell-renderer/
- https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grouping-single-group-column/

Answer (score 0):

Building up on top of Ahmeds solution: you don't really need `cellRenderer` defined and in the recent versions of AGGrid using the 'group' one produces a warning.
Also, as of v27, the property `innerRendererFramework` is deprecated.You should use `innerRenderer` instead:

```
{
    headerName: 'Whatever',
    cellRendererParams: {
        innerRenderer: MyCustomCellRendererComponent
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You need first to register the components. See in their documentation. It's pretty easy actually. The inside columnDef you just do `cellRenderer: 'yourComponent',`

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-components/#registering-framework-components

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, for an ordinary column we can set cellRendererFramework and it works well. But, If we use tree data, we don't have a columnDef for hierarchy column, its configuration goes to GridOptions.autoGroupColumnDef. The question is: can we provide more advanced renderer than simpleFunction. I want my renderer to be a fully functional Angular Component.

Comment: Hi, with cellRendererFramework I'm using a fully functional Angular Component and it works fine for me. For simple cases I'll use a function, but I sometimes use a component. See in their documentation also: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/

Comment: yes, I understand how to provide cellRendererFramework for an ordinary column. But, in my case it's Tree Data hierarchy column that is responsible for expanding/collapsing tree. I've tried to provide cellRendererFramework there, but it haven't worked for me. I feel confused about TreeData documentation in ag-grid

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone still needs the answer:

Instead of using **cellRenderer** property to provide the renderer component in a regular column, you need to provide **innerRenderer** property inside **cellRendererParams** of autoGroupCloumnDef.

Like this: 
[example from ag-grid documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A68aG.png)